# sorting list of coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I sort the list below based on the **b** component instead of the **a** component if I use the `sorted()`method in Python

```
list = [(a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the sort-key to set a specific function to decide the sorting criterion. In this case it might be enough to just pick the second value for each entry, i.e. `x[1]`. See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for more information on the `sort` and `sorting` functions.

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

and, for example, if you notice that you want to sort in descending and not ascending order:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: -x[1])
```